# CASE statement in WHERE clause with IN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I have a `CASE` statement with an `IN` condition in the `WHERE` clause of an SQL Server query?

I am trying to return all the UK events when `@DivisionCode = 'UK'` else all events for US and CA.

I have tried this but with no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM Events
WHERE Division IN (CASE WHEN @DivisionCode = 'UK' THEN 'UK' ELSE 'CA,' + 'US' END))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `case` in the `where`.  Just use boolean logic:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Events e
WHERE (@DivisionCode = 'UK' AND Division = 'UK') OR
      (@DivisionCode <> 'UK' AND Division IN ('CA', 'US'));
```

This assumes that `@DivisionCode` is not `NULL`.  `NULL` values can easily be incorporated into the logic, if that is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're after Boolean Logic:

```
SELECT {columns}
FROM dbo.Events E
WHERE (E.Division = 'UK' AND @DivisionCode = 'UK')
   OR (E.Division IN ('CA','US') AND @DivisionCode IS NULL); --Assumes DivisionCode won't have a value
```

The problem with this, however, is that what you kind of have is a catch-all query. Therefore, you **might** have a poorly cached query plan for the query you're running. One way to deal with this would be to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the query, to create the query plan each time. Otherwise, you could use `IF` Logic and 2 statements:

```
IF @DivisionCode = 'UK'
    SELECT {columns}
    FROM dbo.Events E
    WHERE E.Division = 'UK';
ELSE
    SELECT {columns}
    FROM dbo.Events E
    WHERE E.Division IN ('US','CA');
```

For the simplicity we have, I would say the latter would be better.

*Note: There are not `Case` statements in T-SQL. What you have an a `CASE` expression. `Case` statements are similar to an `IF` and change the logical "flow" of SQL, where an an expression returns a scalar value.*